# How to redirect from url: https://myfavourite.test.com/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=/ to url: https://myfavourite.test.com/ using IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Can anyone help me to know how I can redirect the url: https://myfavourite.test.com/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=/ to the url: https://myfavourite.test.com/ using IIS7.5

I have implemented ADFS for authentication of my application. The application is developed using ASP.NET MVC2.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Comment: refer this http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks

Comment: I am using ADFS for authentication so I cannot modify the Account controller's LogOn action method. I want to redirect the user to the base url: https://myfavourite.test.com/.Is there any way to do this using IIS 7.5 modules.

Comment: hope this will be help ful http://www.vankeyenberg.be/?cat=101

Comment: This link gives details of ADFS implementation for ASP.NET MVC application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the steps mentioned in the below mentioned article and it helped me.
http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/iis7-url-rewrite-extension-on-windows-server-2008

I used the Redirect option and then added a Blank rule with the following regular expression:

account$|account/(?!LogOff)

and that helped me to resolve the redirection issue.